# How do I get active rows in 1 to many relationship using Linq?

Tags: linq

I am using EF4.3. At the back end I have a database that includes the following tables

[image]

In my site logic, I retrieve the entity Tier, but also eager load MatchNode, MatchBuyer and Buyer.

Here's my logic for fetching all Tier entities:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Tier> Fetch()
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(ConnectionString.Lenders))
        {
            var r = new Repository<Tier>(uow.Context);

            return r.Find()
                .Include("MatchNodes.MatchBuyer.Buyer")           
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, a Tier has many MatchNode, and each MatchNode, a single MatchBuyer and MatchBuyer a single Buyer.

However what I want to do is this. Only include MatchNode's where enabled = true and Buyer: Status = 'Active'.

Is this possible and can it be incorporated into the logic below as a .Where()?

Comment: just as a note you are sure Buyer are 1:1 to MatchBuyer? so you could put that table together

Comment: No, buyer has a buyer type and can be MatchBuyer or CompareBuyer. Each of these has different data. What you can't see behind the scenes is that MatchBuyer is constrained to being of BuyerType.Match via the use of a trigger.

Comment: As an unrelated note, I would like to recommend the type-safe version of the Include method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
 return r.Find()
         .Include("MatchNodes.MatchBuyer.Buyer")   
         .Where(c => c.MatchNodes
                         .Any(c => c.Enabled == true && 
                                   c.MatchBuyer.Buyer.Status == "Active")
                   )        
          .ToList();
```

It will give you all the `Tier`s that has `MatchNodes.Enabled == true`
and `Buyer.Status == "Active"`

**EDIT**
To only return the `MatchNotes` use a `SelectMany`:

```
var lst =   r.Find()
             .Include("MatchNodes.MatchBuyer.Buyer")   
             .Where(c => c.MatchNodes
                             .Any(c => c.Enabled == true && 
                                       c.MatchBuyer.Buyer.Status == "Active")
                       )
              .SelectMany(c => c.MatchNodes)  //<-- SelectMany istead of Select       
              .ToList();
```

**EDIT 2**
Ok - so the above code will find items (`Tiers`) that have *at least one* `MatchNode` where the matchnode is enabled and buyerstatus is actice.

We could change it by replacing `.Any(..)` with a `.All(..)`.
This would return all the `Tiers` where *all* the `MatchNodes` fill the requirment.

Comment: Hi Jens - Is it possible to take this a step further and just return the Enabled MatchNodes?

Comment: @dotnetnoob Yes - I think it is. See my edit - let me know if it works

Comment: My question was probably confusing. The first query is fine except the tier looks like it will return all MatchNodes instead of just the enabled, provided at least one of the MatchNodes is enabled for a tier. I was looking to See if the MatchNodes for each tier could only return enabled nodes.

Comment: I'm going to test this afternoon Jens - will let you know how I get on